# oh-my-zsh startup failure: __git_prompt_git status blocks

Tags: zsh, command-line

[image]

I have been installed iTerm2 and brew. In the process, I have some problems with my terminal. It doesn't show anything whatever I command it. That's all I can do is `/bin/bash` to return to bash. There also appear -tail in front of the zsh. How to change the zsh back to normal?

Could sb give a have a hand with this?
I just want to beautify my terminal.
Greatly appreciate.

---

[image]
This is the sequence after I press `Ctrl-C`.I can't input anything, still. And I press `Ctrl-D`, it shows this.

`Saving session...completed.`

The window just stuck at there. The problem has remained if I reopen it.

.zshrc

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
```

---

I've found the mysterious word `tail`.
[image]

---

oh-my-Zsh.sh

```
# Protect against non-zsh execution of Oh My Zsh (use POSIX syntax here)
[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] || {
  # ANSI formatting function (\033[<code>m)
  # 0: reset, 1: bold, 4: underline, 22: no bold, 24: no underline, 31: red, 33: yellow
  omz_f() {
    [ $# -gt 0 ] || return
    IFS=";" printf "\033[%sm" $*
  }
  # If stdout is not a terminal ignore all formatting
  [ -t 1 ] || omz_f() { :; }

  omz_ptree() {
    # Get process tree of the current process
    pid=$$; pids="$pid"
    while [ ${pid-0} -ne 1 ] && ppid=$(ps -e -o pid,ppid | awk "\$1 == $pid { print \$2 }"); do
      pids="$pids $pid"; pid=$ppid
    done

    # Show process tree
    case "$(uname)" in
    Linux) ps -o ppid,pid,command -f -p $pids 2>/dev/null ;;
    Darwin|*) ps -o ppid,pid,command -p $pids 2>/dev/null ;;
    esac

    # If ps command failed, try Busybox ps
    [ $? -eq 0 ] || ps -o ppid,pid,comm | awk "NR == 1 || index(\"$pids\", \$2) != 0"
  }

  {
    shell=$(ps -o pid,comm | awk "\$1 == $$ { print \$2 }")
    printf "$(omz_f 1 31)Error:$(omz_f 22) Oh My Zsh can't be loaded from: $(omz_f 1)${shell}$(omz_f 22). "
    printf "You need to run $(omz_f 1)zsh$(omz_f 22) instead.$(omz_f 0)\n"
    printf "$(omz_f 33)Here's the process tree:$(omz_f 22)\n\n"
    omz_ptree
    printf "$(omz_f 0)\n"
  } >&2

  return 1
}

# If ZSH is not defined, use the current script's directory.
[[ -z "$ZSH" ]] && export ZSH="${${(%):-%x}:a:h}"

# Set ZSH_CACHE_DIR to the path where cache files should be created
# or else we will use the default cache/
if [[ -z "$ZSH_CACHE_DIR" ]]; then
  ZSH_CACHE_DIR="$ZSH/cache"
fi

# Make sure $ZSH_CACHE_DIR is writable, otherwise use a directory in $HOME
if [[ ! -w "$ZSH_CACHE_DIR" ]]; then
  ZSH_CACHE_DIR="${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/oh-my-zsh"
fi

# Create cache and completions dir and add to $fpath
mkdir -p "$ZSH_CACHE_DIR/completions"
(( ${fpath[(Ie)"$ZSH_CACHE_DIR/completions"]} )) || fpath=("$ZSH_CACHE_DIR/completions" $fpath)

# Check for updates on initial load...
if [ "$DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE" != "true" ]; then
  source $ZSH/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh
fi

# Initializes Oh My Zsh

# add a function path
fpath=($ZSH/functions $ZSH/completions $fpath)

# Load all stock functions (from $fpath files) called below.
autoload -U compaudit compinit

# Set ZSH_CUSTOM to the path where your custom config files
# and plugins exists, or else we will use the default custom/
if [[ -z "$ZSH_CUSTOM" ]]; then
    ZSH_CUSTOM="$ZSH/custom"
fi


is_plugin() {
  local base_dir=$1
  local name=$2
  builtin test -f $base_dir/plugins/$name/$name.plugin.zsh \
    || builtin test -f $base_dir/plugins/$name/_$name
}

# Add all defined plugins to fpath. This must be done
# before running compinit.
for plugin ($plugins); do
  if is_plugin $ZSH_CUSTOM $plugin; then
    fpath=($ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/$plugin $fpath)
  elif is_plugin $ZSH $plugin; then
    fpath=($ZSH/plugins/$plugin $fpath)
  else
    echo "[oh-my-zsh] plugin '$plugin' not found"
  fi
done

# Figure out the SHORT hostname
if [[ "$OSTYPE" = darwin* ]]; then
  # macOS's $HOST changes with dhcp, etc. Use ComputerName if possible.
  SHORT_HOST=$(scutil --get ComputerName 2>/dev/null) || SHORT_HOST=${HOST/.*/}
else
  SHORT_HOST=${HOST/.*/}
fi

# Save the location of the current completion dump file.
if [ -z "$ZSH_COMPDUMP" ]; then
  ZSH_COMPDUMP="${ZDOTDIR:-${HOME}}/.zcompdump-${SHORT_HOST}-${ZSH_VERSION}"
fi

# Construct zcompdump OMZ metadata
zcompdump_revision="#omz revision: $(builtin cd -q "$ZSH"; git rev-parse HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
zcompdump_fpath="#omz fpath: $fpath"

# Delete the zcompdump file if OMZ zcompdump metadata changed
if ! command grep -q -Fx "$zcompdump_revision" "$ZSH_COMPDUMP" 2>/dev/null \
   || ! command grep -q -Fx "$zcompdump_fpath" "$ZSH_COMPDUMP" 2>/dev/null; then
  command rm -f "$ZSH_COMPDUMP"
  zcompdump_refresh=1
fi

if [[ $ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX != true ]]; then
  source $ZSH/lib/compfix.zsh
  # If completion insecurities exist, warn the user
  handle_completion_insecurities
  # Load only from secure directories
  compinit -i -C -d "${ZSH_COMPDUMP}"
else
  # If the user wants it, load from all found directories
  compinit -u -C -d "${ZSH_COMPDUMP}"
fi

# Append zcompdump metadata if missing
if (( $zcompdump_refresh )); then
  # Use `tee` in case the $ZSH_COMPDUMP filename is invalid, to silence the error
  # See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/commit/dd1a7269#commitcomment-39003489
  tee -a "$ZSH_COMPDUMP" &>/dev/null <<EOF

$zcompdump_revision
$zcompdump_fpath
EOF
fi

unset zcompdump_revision zcompdump_fpath zcompdump_refresh


# Load all of the config files in ~/oh-my-zsh that end in .zsh
# TIP: Add files you don't want in git to .gitignore
for config_file ($ZSH/lib/*.zsh); do
  custom_config_file="${ZSH_CUSTOM}/lib/${config_file:t}"
  [ -f "${custom_config_file}" ] && config_file=${custom_config_file}
  source $config_file
done

# Load all of the plugins that were defined in ~/.zshrc
for plugin ($plugins); do
  if [ -f $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh ]; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh
  elif [ -f $ZSH/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh ]; then
    source $ZSH/plugins/$plugin/$plugin.plugin.zsh
  fi
done

# Load all of your custom configurations from custom/
for config_file ($ZSH_CUSTOM/*.zsh(N)); do
  source $config_file
done
unset config_file

# Load the theme
if [ ! "$ZSH_THEME" = ""  ]; then
  if [ -f "$ZSH_CUSTOM/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme" ]; then
    source "$ZSH_CUSTOM/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
  elif [ -f "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme" ]; then
    source "$ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
  else
    source "$ZSH/themes/$ZSH_THEME.zsh-theme"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Looks like some command is running in via your `.zshrc` that's piped to tail, it might wait for input. Press `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-D` to see whether you get a prompt. If so, edit your question and add the content of your `.zshrc`.

Comment: "That's all I can do is /bin/bash to return to bash": How do you do that currently? And, once you've started bash, can you then run `zsh` and see what happens?

Comment: What happens in Terminal.app? What is in your ~/.zshenv and ~/.zshrc ?

Comment: @nohillside It doesn't react to anything.

Comment: Rename your ~/.zshenv and ~/.zshrc, and try again. Then look at the content of these files and search for `tail` (or paste it into the question as text, formatted as code)

Comment: @nohillside It's success!! I rename the file and become normal. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This doesn’t solve the problem though. These files are there for a reason, you still need to fix the content.

Comment: What's in `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`?

Comment: oh... The problem still exists if I rename the file back. It shows 
`zsh: no such file or directory: /oh-my-zsh.sh`
What content should I fix?

Comment: Since you claim that your bash configuration works normally, I would (for debugging) start a bash shell, and from it create with `zsh -lx` an interactive zsh login shell. Chances are high that you can see from it where your mysterious `tail` command hides.

Comment: @user1934428 I just found it!! And how should I remove that nasty word?

Comment: How about using a text editor?

Comment: This seems to be an issue within the git plugin used by  `oh-my-zsh.sh` (see https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/git.zsh). Can you open that file in a text editor and look at the definiton of the function called `parse_git_dirty`?

Comment: oh-my-zsh is not part of zsh it is an additional thing that you have had to explicitly download and add. If you do not know what it is I would remove it. And remove all oh-my-zsh lines from ~/.zshrc

Comment: The relevant file is git.zsh. But might be best to remove oh-my-zsh in full

Comment: `tail` is a symptom, it's not the problem. Based on the code nohillside found, the problem is that `__git_prompt_git status` doesn't work properly: it should complete almost instantly, but on your system it's blocking. Unless there's something highly unusual in your setup, this is a bug in oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for guys trying to help me solve the problem. I think I'll use another Terminal instead.

Answer (score -2):

ZSH home on macOS should be `/bin/zsh`, if you are not using a custom shell. Unless you very explicitly installed oh my zsh (e.g. from here https://ohmyz.sh/) then your issue is that the shell you are telling your Mac to run does not exist on your Mac.

Check your preferences in Terminal - under General, what command is listed for "shells open with"? (For default, Command (complete path) should list `/bin/zsh` - is that what you see?)

For what it's worth, my `.zshrc` is entirely blank. A few entries in `.zshenv` and `.zprofile` only. Everything I run in Terminal works fine.

Comment: Yes, I see the list show `/bin/zsh`. It's fine if I blank the `.zshrc` content out. But I still want to beautify my terminal by oh-my-zsh. Is there any default content that can copy on my `.zshrc`? I wanna try it whether it works or not.